# Функция посимвольного ввода строки до нажатия клавиши ENTER

Tags: c#, строки, функции, консоль

Всем привет. Не дали лабу в универе и нужно сделать это задание на C#, я только начал изучать язык и в строках вообще ничего не понимаю.
Не знаю что и делать, завис на 2 задании: Функция посимвольного ввода строки до нажатия клавиши ENTER.
Первое я уже сделал:

```cs
string input(string message)
{
  Console.Write(message);
  string number = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
  return number;
}
//­ Определения длины строки
int b =0;
string message = input("Введите сроку : ");
     
for(var i =0; i < message.Length; i++)
{
  b++;
}

Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Кто может помочь с решением?
Буду очень благодарен) И еще к условию на скрине идет дополнительное условие: В каждую пару символов 'AB' вставить символ '*', подсчитать, сколько раз в строке символ 'I' стоит перед '2'.

[image: Задание по лабе]

Comment: В вашем вопросе отсутвует вопрос. Непонятно, чего вы хотите то?

Comment: Если не понимаете, значит плохо учат, плохие преподаватели. Задавайте вопросы преподавателю, записывайтесь на дополнительные занятия. Учитесь. В первую очередь учитесь искать и находить информацию для решения задач. Умение хорошо искать - половина любого программиста.

Comment: Согласен с @aepot

Answer (score 0):

Согласно дополнительному условию, как я понимаю, нужно просто вывести строку в консоль, а возвращать её из метода необязательно.

Разбил все пункты задания на отдельные методы для наглядности.

```
public void MainMethod()
    {
        string message = ReadInput();        
        Console.WriteLine(CountChars(message));
        DisplayMessageWithAsterisks(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"\n{CountSlashes(message)}"); // Строка с количеством | перед 2
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ввод значений
    /// </summary>
    string ReadInput()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите строку: ");
        string inputMessage = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(inputMessage); // Выводим отдельно напечатанное нами сообщение
        return inputMessage;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Считаем знаки |
    /// </summary>
    public int CountSlashes(string message)
    {
        int result = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i< message.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((message[i] == '|') && (message[i + 1] == '2') && (i + 1 < message.Length))
            {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выводим новую строку со звёздочками между AB
    /// </summary>
    public void DisplayMessageWithAsterisks(string message)
    {
        int startLength = message.Length;


        for (int i = 0; i < startLength; i++)
        {
            // Условие что A и B идут друг за другом
            if (message[i] == 'A' && message[i + 1] == 'B' )
            {
                // Добавляем в конец строки A*
                message += $"{message[i]}*";
            }
            else
                message += message[i]; // иначе просто дописываем символ в конец строки
        }

        //Выводим на экран добавленную нами часть строки
        for (int i = startLength; i < message.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(message[i]);        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Считаем длину строки
    /// </summary>
    public int CountChars(string message)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Не очень работает. Вставил на 10 и 56 строках вместо ${} - {{}}, начало компилироваться. Но вывода нормального нет. Тестил на dotnetfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Написал работающую программу с подсчетом "стенок" (|) перед первой найденной двойкой и заготовком вставки астериска (не получилось реализовать).

```cs
using System;

namespace App
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string input(string message)
        {
            Console.Write(message);
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }
        
        public static string InsertAsterisks(string str) { // Вставка астерисков после AB [НЕ РАБОТАЕТ]
            int _1 = 0, _2 = 1;
            for (; _1 < str.Length; _1++,_2++) {
                if (Char.ToLower(str[_1]) == 'a' && Char.ToLower(str[_2]) == 'b') {
                    str.Insert(_2 + 1, "*"); // Вставляем астериск после найденной AB
                }
            }
            return str;
        }
        
        public static int CountSignsBefore2(string str) { // Считаем знаки |
            int count = 0;
            int foundIndex = -1; // Индекс, где найден 2.
            
            for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) { // Ищем двойку
                if (str[i] != '2') continue; // К следующей итерации, если символ не равен 2.
                foundIndex = i;
                break; // Выходим из цикла, т. к. двойка уже найдена.
            }
            
            if (foundIndex == -1) return foundIndex; // Если 2 не найдено, возвращаем -1
            
            for (int i = foundIndex-1 /* Первый знак перед 2. */; i >= 0; i--) { // Подсчитываем. Тут используется обратный цикл
                if (str[i] != '|') break; // Либо знаков перед 2 вообще нет (может быть если это вызвано при первой же итерации), либо серия знаков кончилась.
                else count++; // Знак найден. Прибавляем к счету.
            }

            return count;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //­ Определения длины строки
            string message = input("Введите строку: ");
            int b = message.Length; // цикл не нужен

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nИсходная строка: " + message);
            Console.WriteLine("Длина строки:" + b);
            // Console.WriteLine("Вставленные астериски: " + InsertAsterisks(message)); Не удалось сделать.
            Console.WriteLine("Количество | перед 2: " + CountSignsBefore2(message));
        }
    }
}
```

Вот пример вывода:

```cs
Введите строку: Hello World! AB ABAB |||2

Исходная строка: Hello World! AB ABAB |||2
Длина строки: 25
Количество | перед 2: 3
```

Ссылка на DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iIHiEQ